# Thermostat Device Missing from Google Smart Device Management API calls

Tags: google-api, home-assistant, nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I have my project linked to google's new (as of october) SDM OAuth scheme and I am able to talk to `https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/project-id/structures`.

My nest doorbell cameras appear on the json response:

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "name": "enterprises/...",
      "type": "sdm.devices.types.DOORBELL",... ..
```

But the thermostat does not appear here.
I do see it on the nest app itself so I'm pretty sure its all linked. I even see it in the radio check box.

How do you add devices when they are not detected? Is this an account issue, where somehow my thermostat is stuck in Nest legacy and everything else is on the new SDM system?

Comment: Does the thermostat show up in the partner connection manager that you see during the account linking flow? Yes, all devices attached to an account should show up in the API. But if the device is disabled in the Partner Connection Manager then it won't be exposed.

Comment: @Ethan I guess thats the problem  when I try and run `curl -X GET 'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/...`  I get a list of devices[ ] but the thermostat is not one of them. Im not sure where to go to "enable" this devices I didn't perform any action with the cameras and they were discovered. How do I add it?

Comment: something happened with devices in the last few months because this had been working for me and then they disappeared. moving the thermostat to another room and then back from inside the Nest app cleared this problem up for me just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this same issue today: my thermostat had been exposed via the SDM API for months, along with my cameras, but suddenly today the thermostat disappeared from the API despite still showing up with access granted during the account linking flow. Per Greg's suggestion in the comments, I moved the thermostat to a different room in the Nest app and then moved it back, and it's now showing up in my API calls once again. I'd recommend trying that as a solution for anyone else with this issue.